# Saving a COUNT column appearance while printing each row in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

So there is a question I have not been able to find an answer to. Say you want to print each row in a table like the following:

```
ID  | Name | Location
----+------+----------
1   | Adam | New York
2   | Eva  | London
3   | Jon  | New York
```

which would give the result

```
1 Adam New York  
2 Eva London  
3 Jon New York
```

Say that I at the same time would like to count the number of occurrences someone lives in a specific city, and save that value for printing after I've iterated through the table; is that possible? For example, printing the following:

```
1 Adam New York  
2 Eva London  
3 Jon New York  
Inhabitants in New York: 2  
Inhabitants in London: 1
```

Is this possible or would you have to iterate through the entire table twice by grouping by `Location` the second time, and counting those?

EDIT:
To clarify, I know I can solve it by calling:

```
SELECT * FROM table; 
SELECT CONCAT('Inhabitants in ', Location, ': ', COUNT(ID))
FROM table
GROUP BY Location;
```

But now I am iterating through it twice. Is it possible to do it in only one iteration?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Yes, possible!! how you want to handle this. in application side or in procedure?

Comment: In the procedure, as in SQL-language.

Comment: "iterate through the entire table twice by grouping by Location the second time"

Comment: and displaying data as you showed, is not database job  but application

Comment: Sure, but the database has to return something when getting a call.

Comment: So what is your question? how to count data or how to display ?

Comment: SQL queries return a result set with a fixed number of columns and rows that have data for all columns.  What you want to do has rows of different structure, so it is not really possible through a `SELECT` query, unless you do some hack like turning a row into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, displaying every row from the table and displaying aggregated data is two separate tasks which should be handled by application, not by the database.

You have the option to run two queries - a plain `select * from T`, and `select location, count(*) from T group by location`, and displaying results sequentially. You also have the option to run only a  `select * from T` one, and count the rows within your application, since you're displaying all rows anyway: use any dictionary-like structure your app language provides, with location string for key and running total integer for value.

If you're keen on keeping it a single query, check out `WITH ROLLUP` clause - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html. This would certainly be an unusual way of using it, but if you `group by location, id` and then tamper with results a little, you can get what you want.

```
select if(id is null, CONCAT('Inhabitants in ', location, ': ', cnt), concat(id, ' ', name, ' ', location))
from
(
select id, location, name, count(*) cnt
from t
where location is not null
group by location, id with rollup
) q
where location is not null
order by id is null, id asc;
```

Though the performance could be questionable, compared to two plain queries; you should experiment or check with `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this answers my question. I was curious whether it would be more efficient to iterate through the table multiple times instead of finding a way to do it in only one iteration. I'll be sure to experiment a bit more on the issue.

Comment: if you're worried about performance, you can create an index on `location` column. This should make `select location, count(*) from T group by location` query almost instant.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, use subquery

```
select concat(concat(concat('Inhabitants in ',location),':'),total)
from
(select location, count(id) total
from tablename group by location)a
```